# Dragging after scaling/transform in raphael js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, svg-animate

How do I correct the axis of my text after I scaled it? It seem that the mouse pointer is not responsive on the text location. But when initially created I can drag/drop my text responsively to the mouse pointer. Here's a link of my sample project.

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById("area"), 500, 500);
var attr = {"fill":"red","font-family": "arial", "font-size": "50px","cursor":"move"};
var text = paper.text(250, 250, "Some\nTEST").attr(attr);

start = function () {

    this.ox = parseFloat( this.attr("x") );
    this.oy = parseFloat( this.attr("y") );
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    this.attr({x: this.ox + dx, y: this.oy + dy});
    this.odx = dx;
    this.ody = dy;
},
up = function () {
    this.attr({cursor:"move"});
};

text.drag(move, start, up);

$("button.fontsize-control").click(function(){
    var action = $(this).data("action");
    if( action == "down" ){
        text.transform("s.80...");
    }else{
        text.transform("s1.2...");
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/odegraciajr/v48tL/1/)